# How do I replace an attachment in an email with the Rails mail gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

My program is dealing with emails which arrive as files (something.eml). In some circumstances I need to amend an attachment and then resave the file. I've been using the instructions [here](https://github.com/mikel/mail) as a basis for my code, but there's no suggestion for trying to do exactly what I'd like. The code I have below successfully removes the original attachment and then tries to add in a new one.

```
@email.without_attachments!
@email.add_file(amended_version)
```

Unfortunately it goes wrong in two places. Firstly it seems to remove all mime parts, not just attachments. Any text/plain sections are also ditched. Secondly, if I test by reloading my amended .eml file, the attachment is no longer recognised, despite being in the file.

I've included a [gist](https://gist.github.com/3622783) which includes the original and amended files from my current method.

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps a way of replacing the attachment directly rather than get rid of it and adding again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know enough about mail formatting to know why this works, but it does.

I extracted just the line I was interested in from the [without_attachments!](http://rdoc.info/github/mikel/mail/master/Mail/Message%3awithout_attachments!) method and it now seems to work fine. The non-attachment parts of the message are kept intact and the message re-reads fine. Code now reads....

```
@email.parts.delete_if { |p| p.attachment? }
@email.add_file(amended_version)
```